# How to express the generalising "life has a way of ..."?

Tags: выражения

In conversation, I just said:

> Думаешь, что ты на коне, а жизнь снова **отвешивает** тебе оплеуху.

Here I wanted to express the idea of "life **has a way of** ...". In English, this expression refers to the way how something generally happens, as in "Life has a (funny) way of working out just when you start to believe it never will" or "Sailing has a way of growing on you".

I wonder if in Russian the imperfective aspect "отвешивает" – as opposed to perfective – was enough to make a sweeping generalisation about how things work? That is, without adding another word such as "жизнь **умеет** ..." or "жизнь **способна** ..."?

What is a commonly used phrasing for this in Russian?

Comment: yes, pretty much, it may be alluded to the verb **бывает** which also expresses usual or periodical occurrence of something, but future perfective will also work provided **снова** is kept, or it may be phrased as **возьми да и отвесь**... as for the actual parallel of the English phrase about life in particular, one can say **жизнь может/способна так круто повернуться/измениться, что...** (couldn't avoid **способна**) or **жизнь умеет преподносить такие сюрпризы, что...**

Comment: or probably a parallel Russian expression would be **у ... есть (такое) свойство + impf. infinitive**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use *она такая* или *дело такое*:

> Жизнь — она такая, всё налаживается, когда в это уж и верить отчаялся.
>
> Парусный спорт — дело такое, захватывает.

Another option is to use *имеет свойство*:

> В жизни всё имеет свойство налаживаться тогда, когда уже отчаялся в это верить.
>
> Есть у парусного спорта такое свойство, захватывать.

Comment: "она такая, (что) всё налаживается" / "дело такое, (что) захватывает" Hi. Is "что" after "такая/такое" commonly dropped in the colloquial language?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens: yes, and in fact you can't even use it with *что*. Technically you can say *парусный спорт такой, что он захватывает*, but this would be a weird way to put it and it would definitely lose the idiomatic meaning.